# detecting if it's the home page in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to detect if the current page is the home page in my fresh install of WordPress.

The snippet of code below works in page.php but it does not work in functions.php. How can i detect for the homepage in functions.php in WordPress?

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    echo 'test';
}
```

I know I can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but I figured there should be a better way of doing this.

In the wordpress Settings > Reading, I have a static page for my home page. is_home() does not work in my page.php but is_front_page() does work in my page.php. Both these functions do not work in my functions.php

Comment: Without any additional code it's hard to tell. Can you provide more of the code in `functions.php` that you're working with?

Comment: The raw code in functions.php is run way before WordPress starts figuring out which page/template it's going to use. What are you actually trying to achieve? You probably want to hook into an action or filter so your code to test `is_front_page` is set up to run later on, at a point when WordPress has set up enough things to answer that question... From [the notes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home): "`is_home` uses the global $wp_query WP_Query object. is_home isn't usable before the parse_query action." So you'll need to defer running it until that late at least.

Comment: I want to load some scripts and css only for the home page in functions.php. Thats what Im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use the `is_home()` conditional tag to check for homepage

**EDIT**

From your comments, what you are trying will never work. You need to add your code inside a function and then hook it to some hook

```
<?php
function my_custom_function() {
    if(is_front_page()){ 
        echo "home"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "not home"; 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_function' );
```

You are also stating **in a comment** that you want to load styles and scripts on the frontpage only. You can try the following

```
<?php
function my_custom_function() {
    if(is_front_page()){ 
       //Load your styles and scripts
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_function' );
```

Comment: In the wordpress Settings > Reading, I have a static page for my home page. is_home() does not work in my page.php but is_front_page() does work in my page.php.

Both these functions do not work in my empty functions.php

Comment: Thanks. is_front_page() worked inside the wp_enqueue_scripts action in functions.php.